FourierTransform result different than expected
FourierTransform[Exp[-a t]*UnitStep[t], t, w] gives the following result
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } (a-i w)},$$
but the answer should be
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi } (a+i w)}.$$
Why does Mathematica return an additional negative sign?

Are you using the same definition (i.e., FourierParameters) as the default for the FourierTransform?

Why do you assume that your result is correct and Mathematica's wrong?

You can find what Parameters to use as follows (modified to use parameters $c_1,c_2$ instead of what Mathematica calls $a,b$ as there is an $a$ already in the input. Less confusing):
e = Exp[-a*t]*UnitStep[t]
FourierTransform[e,t,w,FourierParameters->{c[1],c[2]}]


To move the sqrt down stairs then need $c_1=0$ to be zero
FourierTransform[e, t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, c[2]}]


To get the plus sign you want, then make $c_2=-1$
 FourierTransform[e, t, w, FourierParameters -> {0, -1}]


Mathematica FourierTransform uses default {0,1}

Thank you for your answer. I calculated the transform by hand and there is suppose to be a negative sign. So Mathematica does give the correct answer. It turns out that the text book I have is incorrect and has a typo.
Thanks again !
Jeff
